# Deleted class drops error message unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory:

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bitbucket, viewcontroller

So me and some friends working on a bitbucket project and already realized that bitbucket sometimes doesn't sync all the files. But here is what happened:

I continued working and created an class, I basically copied an old View Controller (called `WelcomescreenViewController.swift` -> `CreateAccountViewController.swift`) and made some adjustments in the main storyboard. Here I deleted all the old outlets in the new one and then made an own class for it as ViewController and connected it with it in the main storyboard.

What now happened is that there were some problems and I reverted everything and deleted both things again. And basically now Xcode still kind of thinks that there should be the class. It always drops the message:

[image]

I also made a screenshot from the directory with my files as it is now:

[image]

I tried to create the class again, so that Xcode is happy but it doesn't help. Is the file somewhere linked or what shall I do, to teach Xcode hey everything is fine, don't mind about the old file `CreateAccountViewController.swift`?

Comment: have you tried cleaning your build folder and relaunching Xcode?

Comment: yeah I did. Didn't help =/

Comment: Have your searched the entire project for occurrences of "CreateAccountViewController"?

Comment: Just did it, didn't find anything left. So I don't know if there is somewhere a relation left in the settings somewhere or what is keeping the problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure in your target settings, under **Build Phases > Compile Sources** that your file isn't listed there:

[image]

Also, just check it somehow hasn't been added to **Copy Bundle Resources**.

[image]

Comment: lifesaver... costed me like half an hour... thank you

Comment: Saved my day and/or days.

Comment: i have a file correct in Compile Sources.. but i don't know because have problems with xcode. maybe exists if others options respect this problem

Comment: I wish I could up this answer 1,000 times. Helped SO much

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a pod, and the deleted file is in the pod, try `pod install` to rebuild the framework.

Comment: I had one more target and I didn't update my Podfile with `target 'XXX' do ... end`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the deleted files are still in Project, if yes, delete. build ...